# Is this correct? (No comma after still)

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence correct?

> Jared loudly knocked on the door with a force that would be considered
>   as smashing by neighbors, but still no one opened it

Or do I need another comma after *still*?

> Jared loudly knocked on the door with a force that would be considered
>   as smashing by neighbors, but still, no one opened it

Putting a comma after *still* is looking awkward to me.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to put a comma after still. Unless you want to pause after still and emphasize the time that Jared waited for someone to open the door.